# SQLite ускорить SELECT

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

```
ObservableCollection<Log> logs = new ObservableCollection<Log>();
using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.connection)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT id, text FROM logs", connection)) {
      using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(reader.Read()) {
          logs.Add(new Log() {
            Id = (long)reader[0],
            Text = (string)reader[1]
          });
        }
      }
    }
  connection.Close();
}
```

При примерно 4500 строк запрос занимает 5 - 10 секунд. Как можно ускорить SELECT в SQLite?

Comment: Вы уверены что сам SELECT занимает 5-10 секунда, а не ваши действия с `logs.Add`?

Comment: @gil9red нет, каким образом мне тогда получить коллекцию?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужны сразу все 4500 записей? догружайте частями при необходимости.

Comment: View привязан к этой коллекции во время загрузки? Или привязываетесь после загрузки уже?

Comment: @АндрейNOP после, да думал о загрузке частями, но странно что в SQLite можно вставить много и быстро без проблем с помощю транзакции а получить нет

Comment: Виртуализация в GUI используется? В общем для начала точно определите что именно тормозит — загрузка из БД или всё же отрисовка GUI

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос. Ну и асинхронность конечно же нужна

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, попробую